# SpringBoot: push messages in Controller layer not in Service Layer

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller

SpringBoot is a responsive web framework where the server receives a request and returns a response to the client.

Both requests and responses are processed at the Controller layer;

But now I come across a scenario where we need to actively push messages to the client. The usual approach is to construct a response in the Service layer and return it to the client.

eg:

```
push messages to websocket pipeline
push messages to mq queue
```

But we want this response to be sent at the controller layer instead of the service layer. Is there any solution?